# I need advise on how to code a troubleshooter

Tags: python-3.x

im really new to python and im having trouble

essentially I want to be able to ask questions get a response and ask another question **depending** on the answer, this might be hard to explain so I have somewhat of a picture diagram
[im coding somewhat like this atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDAzU.png)
[I need to code more like this, the questions are irrelevant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psnPU.gif) 
    name=input('What is your name?')
    print ('Nice to meet you' +name)
    print ('Welcome to my troubleshooter')

```
shooter = True
while shooter:
   print(""" 
   1.Enter troubleshooter
   2.Exit

   Press enter to start
   """)
   shooter=input('Please select a option')
   if shooter=="1":
                print('Thankyou, valid customer!')
   elif shooter=="2":
                print('Have a nice day!')

systemq1=input('Does your iPhone turn on?').lower
if systemq1== 'yes':
      print('Great')
else:('Is it Physically damaged')

systemq2=input('Are you using ios 7.1 or later?').lower
if systemq2== 'yes':
   print('Ok')
else:

 systemq3=input('Fixed?').lower
if systemq3== 'Yes':
     print('Great')
elif systemq3== 'No':
     print('Ok.')
else:
     print('Type yes or no.')


systemq4=input('Is your device jailbroken?')
if systemq4== 'Yes':
   print('We should be able to revert it' +name)
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question? I suggest you take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: Well the I'm asking for someone to write a small block of code that I can see so I can apply it to my code

Comment: then your question is off-topic as this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.